# How to optimize this query as this strted hanging due to large "IN" clause

Tags: mysql

I have followinf query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
                        device_id
                        )
                        FROM ABC
                        WHERE app_id ='$appid'
                        AND device_type='Android'                       
                        AND device_id
                        IN (
                                SELECT device_id
                                FROM XYZ
                                WHERE application_id = '$appid'
                                AND device_type='Android'
                                AND device_mode='$device_mode'

                            )
```

In the IN clause I am having array of 6000+ items. So it start hanging. Please let me know how can I optimize this.

PS: I have read other solution, try to use join but still its hanging.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. So using parentheses after `DISTINCT` is unnecesssary

Comment: Do you have indexing on `application_id`, `device_type` and `device_mode` ?

Comment: I would think an `INNER JOIN` would perform somewhat better than an `IN` clause in this scenario.  6000 rows is not a lot so if that's giving you performance issues it's likely to be an indexing issue on your textual columns (as indicated in comments already)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test the query, but it shouldn't be difficult to adjust this or rewrite it as necessary. Instead of large `IN()` list, simply perform an `INNER JOIN` and supply correct `WHERE`

```
SELECT first.device_id 

FROM ABC first

INNER JOIN XYZ second ON first.device_id = second.device_id

WHERE first.app_id = '$appid' 

AND first.device_type = 'Android' 
AND second.application_id = '$appid' 
AND second.device_type = 'Android' 
AND second.device_mode = '$device_mode'

GROUP BY first.device_id
```